# Vector fields, Integral curves and Lie brackets

Tags: smooth-manifolds, vector-fields

This question is from my assignment in manifolds and I am following the book introduction to smooth manifolds.

> Question: Let X,Y and Z be vector fields on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $\sigma : I \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be the integral curve of X starting at 0, where I is some open interval containing 0. If $Y(\sigma(t))= Z(\sigma(t))$ for all $t\in I$, show that $[X,Y](0) = [X,Z](0)$.

Simplifying using the definition of Lie brackets I get: $[X,Y](0) = [X,Z](0)= (X) (Y(0)- Z(0)) = (Y-Z) (X(0))$.

But the problem I am facing is that I don't know how use $Y(\sigma(t))= Z(\sigma(t))$ and thus I am not able to move foreward.

Can you please give me hints on how to use the information given in the question?

I shall be really thankful.

Comment: For vector fields $X,Y$ on $\Bbb{R}^n$, you can think of them as smooth maps $X,Y:\Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}^n$, and their Lie bracket is related to the directional derivatives as follows: $[X,Y](p)= (D_{X(p)}Y)(p)-(D_{Y(p)}X)(p)$. Here I'm using the notation $(D_vF)(p):=\frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t=0}F(p+tv)$, for the directional derivatives, where $v\in\Bbb{R}^n$ is a vector and $F:\Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}^n$ is a vector field. Can you see why you can now replace $Y$ with $Z$?

Comment: Anyway, to be really proper, the question should be "prove $[X,Y](\sigma(0))=[X,Z](\sigma(0))$".

Comment: @peek-a-boo I am sorry but I am not able to see how Y can be replaced with Z. Rest of your 1st comment I understand. Can you please elaborate on it preferrably by writing an answer?

Comment: @peek-a-boo Can you please reply to my comment above?